# MarkupCore - Applying pan and zoom from drawing to multiple markups

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a few hundred markups that were loaded with MarkupCore on some drawing (***v1***).

Right now, I have a new version of that drawing (***v2***) that has different dimensions. Instead of creating all the same markups for that new version, I've copied all the markups in ***v1*** to be used in ***v2***. Since the new version has different dimensions, the position and zoom of the new markups are slightly off.

I have a way for a user to go in ***v2***, without showing the new markups, and pan and zoom until they're sure the drawing placement is right.

How can I extract and apply the pan and zoom that the user applied to drawing, to all the markups, so that their placement is correct?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, markups generated by MarkupCore ext don't contain zoom and pan info. Instead, we suggest getting the zoom and pan info (i.e. camera status) via `viewer.getState()` and restoring it by `viewer.restoreState(viewerStatePersist)`. See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension

Therefore, if your user changed the zoom and pan info on the v2 drawing, you can call `viewer.getState()` again to get new camera status and replace the original one stored in your database(!?).

If just want to get new camera status, we can call the API like this `viewer.getState({ viewport: true })`.